# Concatenate URL when form is submited

Tags: javascript, html, forms, leaflet

I am implementing a simple search application and I am using django and yelp API as my backend and its working fine, my problem is with my frontend(which I am not good at) which I am trying to implement with leaflet,js. In my search app, I have a form with an input tag where the user can search for a restaurant or bank

```
<form id="search_fm" method="get" >
            <input type="text" id="q" name="q" />
            <input type="submit" id="Go" value="Search"  />
 </form>
```

For the location for which I want to display the restaurant or bank I get the lat and lng using `leaflet` function `map.getCenter()`

My problem is how to combine the latlng with my form action. If I can get the request in the format `/search/?q=input_value&loc=latlng`, I can get the request and handle it in my backend.

I tried to concatenate my url with the following code but latlng is not appending

```
var frmSomething= $("#search_fm");
var btnSubmit= $("#Go");
btnSubmit.click(function()
  {
   txt_val = document.getElementById('q').value
   var mLat = map.getCenter().lat
   var mLng =  map.getCenter().lng
   var latlng = mLat +','+ mLng
   console.log(latlng)
   frmSomething.attr("action", "/search/?q=" + txt_val+"&loc="+latlng);
   btnSubmit.submit();
 });
```

Any suggestions

Comment: Does your `console.log(latlng)` display a reasonable value?

Comment: yes, the latlng value is printed in my console

Answer (score 1):

I don't know it an optimal solution but a solution is good without one. What I did is add a hidden input tag in the form and when the button is clicked the latlng value will be assigned to the input tag and I append it to my form action

```
<script>
    var btnSubmit= $("#btnSubmit");
        btnSubmit.click(function()
        {
         var mLat = map.getCenter().lat
         var mLng =  map.getCenter().lng
         var latlng = mLat +','+ mLng
         document.getElementById("loc").value = latlng
         btnSubmit.submit();
        });

</script>                   
<form action="/search/?q='+document.getElementById('q').value'+loc='+document.getElementById('loc')'" id= 'search_fm' method="get" >
  <input type="text" id="q" name="q" />
  <input type="hidden" id="loc" name="loc"/>
  <button id="btnSubmit" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```